# (VS Comm./VB6) How to Select from 2 different data sources/formats in one query?

Tags: mysql, oracle, visual-studio

I have two working TableAdapterQueries in my project, one selects from a MySQL database on a virtual server I own, the other is an Oracle PL/SQL database on a separate server.

The data (and datatypes) in the MySQL database *come from* the Oracle Database. The point of the script will be synchronisation of a sort.

What I fundamentally want to do is something like this, in a query

```
Dataset3 = "Select ID_Column From OracleDB.Tablename
             where OracleDB.TableName.FieldName NOT IN (
                     Select ID_Column From MySQL.Tablename)"
```

To be clear, I have 1 Dataset/Datatable connecting to Oracle fine, one connecting to MySQL fine, I just need to write back to the MySQL one with values found, not found, and changed.

i.e.  'Select from Oracle where not in MySQL' would give a list of all items that need to be added to MySQL table.

'Select from MySQL where not in Oracle' is a list of items that need to be removed, and

'Update MySQL[field] where in Oracle

Is this all doable in VS Community now that I have working Datatable connections?

I'm doing this in VB where possible as I'm most comfortable with debugging and writing it. I'd accept a .NET or C# answer if it were clear how to modify it.

Even if the 'answer' to this question is just a googling topic suggestion. I have found stuff on LINQ to two data bases, but it's all compiled in solutions that are quite hard to read and understand, let alone adapt to my application

Thanks